# How to identify user using mobile data from esim or physical sim in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to know that user using mobile data from esim or physical sim in iOS and also which sim card is active.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get this information from Apple's **private** APIs only, using `CTCellular` but this is definitely not a recommendation unless you are a Carrier and have permission to use the APIs.

`CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` provides some information about the carriers that are subscribed to on the user's device, but not whether it is esim/sim.

```swift
import CoreTelephony

let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
debugPrint(networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders)
```

**Will provide you with this:**

```
Carrier name: [EE]
Mobile Country Code: [<nil>]
Mobile Network Code:[<nil>]
ISO Country Code:[<nil>]
Allows VOIP? [YES]
```

Check out the documentation - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony

Comment: If i want to check for eSIM network then how should i identify. In my case i need to identify only eSIM network @RichAppz

Comment: That's what I am saying it is not currently possible unless you have permission from Apple to gain access to private API's

Answer (score 0):

The data services identifiers aren't reliable, but last time I checked, a dataServiceIdentifier of "0000000100000001" = physical and anything else is eSIM.

Comment: Has Apple mentioned in any of the docs that "0000000100000001" = physical sim?
If yes, could you pls share link?

Comment: Hi Saurabh, sorry I wasn't clearer.  When I said they aren't reliable, it is because Apple haven't documented them.  My checking was via the debugger with a physical device with two sims, one physical, one eSim.