# Is there API for checking if eSIM is installed in iphone?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, react-native

I need to check, is `esim` installed in `iphone`.
Using `react-native` for creating app. Found `react-native-carrier-info`
which uses `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` and `CTCarrier`

Can `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` and `CTCarrier` show if `esim` installed or  some info about this to make such conclusion?
On simulator I could not see any info

Read [coretelephony](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony?changes=latest_minor)
But I am not sure, is there native api for this task or which api can help me to make such conclusion

Answer (score 3):

In Swift, if you want to check eSim connectivity **only**, you can :

```
  // First, check if the currentRadioAccessTechnology is nil
  // It means that no physical Sim card is inserted
  let telephonyInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
  if telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology == nil {
    // Next, on iOS 12 only, you can check the number of services connected
    // With the new serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology property
    if #available(iOS 12, *) {
      if let radioTechnologies =
        telephonyInfo.serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology, !radioTechnologies.isEmpty {
        // One or more radio services has been detected,
        // the user has one (ore more) eSim package connected to a network
      }
    }
  }
```

You can reinforce checking by using the new `supportsCellularPlan()` method on `CTCellularPlanProvisioning`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that is to help you:

Basically do you need to create a Library to access the native library in `Objective-C`:

```
1 - npm install -g react-native-create-library
2 - react-native-create-library MyLibrary
3 - npm install
```

And into a new Library do you implement your access a native library:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface NetworkInfo : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

Implementation:

```
// NetworkInfo.m
#import "NetworkInfo.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation NetworkInfo

// To export a module named NetworkInfo
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
}

@end
```

And in your Javascript:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
var NetworkInfo = NativeModules.NetworkInfo;
```

....your code

For further information:[native-modules-ios](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios)

Comment: Thanks for answer. What Is NetworkInfo api? I could not find it on https://developer.apple.com/documentation?changes=latest_minor
And NetworkInfo - will provide me any info about esim ?

Comment: The NetworkInfo was the name that I put for example, do you put the name that you to want. The class created in this example to able access the native library´s objective c and you can get information the eSim through the library describe here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony and to the solution to your request look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644502/detect-if-sim-card-is-available-in-iphone-programmatically

Comment: Oh I see. But the main question is - which native api can help me to get info about esim ( installed or not or may be help me to make such conclusion). 
and seems CTTelephonyNetworkInfo and CTCarrier do not help me with my problem according  to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55520052/9136852

Comment: So, I try to create a example to you when I arrive in my home, at the moment I´m in my work. Sorry not to help you right now. :(

Comment: Hello! I implement a example and put it on git https://github.com/lucklpn/SimCardInfo I used the example that I found in this site https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-carrier-info I did find easier to implement this. I hope to help you! ;)

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will test this in few days

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple!

Supports **iOS 12+**, Make sure to test it on eSim supported devices.

```html
import CoreTelephony

func eSimSupported() -> Bool {
    let telephonyInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    guard let radioTechnologies =
            telephonyInfo.serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology,
          !radioTechnologies.isEmpty else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

print("eSimSupported = \(eSimSupported())")
```